# Folium Choropleth Map is blank when i try to plot it

Tags: python, data-visualization, geospatial, folium, choropleth

I am trying to Plot some categorical Data in the Indian Meteorological Sub-divisional boundaries. Following is what my geodataframe looks like -
[GeoDataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOZ2e.jpg)
I am using Folium's Choropleth to plot the data onto the geometry mentioned in the same.

```
choropleth_map = folium.Map(location = [78.6677428, 22.3511148], zoom_start=5, tiles='cartodbpositron')

Choropleth(geo_data = gdf, data = gdf, columns = ['OBJECTID_1', 'Value'], key_on = 'feature.properties.OBJECTID_1', fill_color = 'YlGnBu').add_to(choropleth_map)

choropleth_map
```

But all I get is a blank map with a legend. Can you tell me why my plot doesn't work. This is what the plot looks like (blank map with a colorscale) -
[Map Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJSn4.jpg)